# Redirect when login after build -- prod, Using Angular 5

Tags: angular, http

After build --prod, when I login the http request is sent to the server, but when it back the page reload (redirect to the same page)
and I get no errors in the console log.

It is working in ng serve.

(The production server is running on Apache)

I also build ng build --prod --base-href http://system.******.com/

**Service provider code**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable()
export class UserServiceService {

baseUrl: string = 'http://api.equity.com.eg/api/';
private _options = { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type':'application/json' }) };

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

}

login(userData){
let _options = {headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})};
return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}login`, JSON.stringify(userData), _options);
// .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

**Component Code:**

```
  goToHome() {

    this.userService.login(this.userLogin).subscribe((data: any) => {    
      this.errMsg = false;
      this.cookieService.set('token', data.token);
      window.localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);    
      let test = this.cookieService.get('token');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('pages');
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.errMsg = true;
    });
```

**.htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine On 
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html 
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

I tried to change how the http request sent from the service provider to the old http Angular 4 way (.map) and the same problem occurs.
Also I tried to change the .htacces with other rules from the forums for angular in production, the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally**, the problem was happening because uglify not preventing form default behavior in angular cli  **@angular/cli@1.6.2**
so they solved it in in **@angular/cli@1.6.3**
to fix it install the latest cli global

```
$ npm uninstall -g angular-cli
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

then in the **angular project folder**

```
$ rm -rf node_modules dist
$ npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
$ npm install
```